# Is it legal to enter the UK through the common travel area following a refusal of entry at a uk airport?

Tags: uk, ireland, common-travel-area

I read in a fairly impressive and thorough TSE answer that it was but was then told by my solicitor today that that is rubbish.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am going to repeat the quotation I gave in a previous answer on this:

The [Home Office Guidance for the Common Travel Area](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/879600/common-travel-area-v7.0ext.pdf#page32), updated in April 2020, has this to say about your situation:

> **People without leave who have previously been refused leave to enter the UK**
>
> A person who has been refused entry and has not since been given leave to enter or remain requires leave to enter. Where you notice such a person arriving in the UK from within the CTA, you must submit them to further examination in the usual way. If you decide to refuse leave to enter, you must give directions for removal either to:

> - the place within the CTA from which the passenger arrived
> - another appropriate country

> If such a person enters without leave and is subsequently noticed, they are an illegal entrant and they may be removed without refusal of leave to enter under paragraph 9 of schedule 2 of the Immigration Act 1971.

Its right there in the guidance -

- *A person who has been refused entry and has not since been given leave to enter or remain requires leave to enter.*
- *If such a person enters without leave and is subsequently noticed, they are an illegal entrant and they may be removed without refusal of leave to enter under paragraph 9 of schedule 2 of the Immigration Act 1971.*

It is not legal to enter the UK via the Common Travel Area if you have been refused entry previously and not subsequently been granted leave to enter.

Comment: Hmm, what does "removed without refusal of leave" mean, by the way?

Comment: @JosephP. they dont need to issue you with a refusal (as a "refusal of leave to enter" might be appealable in some circumstances, so this prevents that appeals process from being available), you are just removed from the country.

Comment: I see. Well it seems given anyway that the subject in question would have already received a refusal for which the appeals process is still available.. am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @JosephP. yes, you are missing something - the original refusal is entirely separate to the subsequent illegal entry and overstay.  You can be removed without refusal for the latter and any pending outcome of any appeal on the former would have utterly zero bearing on that.

Comment: So if you were able to successfully appeal the initial refusal you would still be banned? I don't understand the significance of removal on its own other than the obvious immediate physical effect. I mean if you've been removed with refusal and then removed without refusal does that somehow take away the previous refusal as a grounds for appealing against the general stance of not allowing you in?

Comment: @JosephP. any successful appeal to a previous refusal would not wipe the slate clean with regard to the subsequent illegal entry and overstay - the two situations are only linked by the fact that they refer to the same person, thats it, in all other ways they are separate events and as such have their own outcomes.  You might be successful with the appeal for a prior refusal, but that doesn't make good the fact that you separately broke the law by entering via the CTA when you were not eligible to do so, and also it doesn't make good the overstay, which would be unlawful anyway.

Comment: Right. As an aside, I don't think there's any mention of overstays in this question, but anyway, should it not be clarified which specific types of applications such breakages of the law may and may not have any bearing on? At one extreme end of the spectrum, I suppose that a visa-free visitor's leave would be virtually out of the question by official principles. On the other, asylum or other human rights applications are not affected in the least by such records of wrongdoing.

Comment: Would you agree with that?

Comment: @JosephP. that would be a different question with a different answer imho.